# String.charAt() returning undefined in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, charat

It must be that I'm missing something big here. For some reason .charAt(i) returns undefined in this piece of code.

#### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5rczhsub/)

```js
    let images = {};
    let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let imageArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
        let letter = alphabet.charAt[i]; // returns undefined
        images[letter] = imageArray[i];
    }

    console.log(images); // {undefined: "d"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a function call of [`String#charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

```
alphabet.charAt(i);
//             ^ ^
```

instead of a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets.

```js
let images = {};
let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let imageArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
  let letter = alphabet.charAt(i); // returns undefined
  images[letter] = imageArray[i];
}

console.log(images); // {undefined: "d"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your syntax! You want to call the `alphabet.charAt` function, of course. But you're doing `charAt[i]` instead of `charAt(i)`. Square brackets are the syntax for accessing a property of an array/object by a variable (`i`), so you end up getting a property *of the function* `charAt` - for example `charAt[0]`. But that doesn't exist, so it just evaluates to `undefined`.

So, to fix this, just replace the square brackets (`charAt[i]`) with parentheses (`charAt(i)`). You always use parentheses to call a function, not square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `.charAt()` function as a function like `.charAt(i)` instead of `.charAt[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is it!, alphabet.charAt() is function, not array. change [] to () and it starts to work.

```
let images = {};
let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let imageArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    let letter = alphabet.charAt(i); // returns undefined
    images[letter] = imageArray[i];
}

console.log(images); // {undefined: "d"}
```